# I don't have a "Desktop" bookmark in nautilus, but in Thunar?

Tags: arch-linux, nautilus, freedesktop

I have xdg users configured manually, in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` I have:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Various"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Papers/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/Misc/Musics/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/Application/Videos/"
```

But nautilus just don't show the Desktop folder,

[image]

How should I fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNOME 3, Nautilus no longer manages the `DESKTOP`. In other words, there is no `DESKTOP` hence `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` is meaningless to Nautilus. You'll have to re-enable the `DESKTOP` in order to have it among other Nautilus bookmarks in the side pane, either through `Gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
Have file manager handle the desktop [ON]
```

or, in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background true
```

Comment: I don't want to see desktop icon and that's way i have set the value to "false" but the Desktop bookmark icon also get hide from nautilus. Is there any way to keep Desktop bookmark in nautilus?

Comment: BTW, this is not related to the original question @don_crissti